# Subdocument merge issue when MongoDB Rust Driver is used

Tags: mongodb, rust

What's wrong with the following snippet:

```
    ...
    let collection: Collection<CodeData> = db.collection(CODE_DATA_COLLECTION);

    let mut memory_breakpoints_update = Document::new();
    for address in start_address..=end_address {
        memory_breakpoints_update
            .insert(address.to_string(), doc! { "read": read, "write": write });
    }

    match collection
        .update_many(
            doc! { "game": game_name},
            doc! { "$set": {
               "memory_blocks": {
                   "$mergeObjects": [ memory_breakpoints_update, "$memory_blocks" ]
               }
            }},
            None,
        )
        .await
    ...
```

Expected that subdocument memory_blocks will be updated. Instead, I got

```
  "memory_breakpoints": {
    "$mergeObjects": [
      {
        "240": {
          "read": true,
          "write": false
        },
        "241": {
          "read": true,
          "write": false
        },
        "242": {
          "read": true,
          "write": false
        },
        "243": {
          "read": true,
          "write": false
        },
        "244": {
          "read": true,
          "write": false
        },
        "245": {
          "read": true,
          "write": false
        }
      },
      "$memory_breakpoints"
    ]
  },
```

On other side, this code works fine in Mongo playground:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "memory_breakpoints": {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            "10": {
              "read": false,
              "write": true
            },
            "11": {
              "read": false,
              "write": true
            }
          },
          "$memory_breakpoints"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4ugz3ayBdhb)

As a temp solution, had to use a brutal force:

```
pub async fn update_memory_breakpoints(
    db: &State<Database>,
    game_name: &String,
    start_address: i32,
    end_address: i32,
    read: bool,
    write: bool,
) -> Result<bool, ....> {
    let collection: Collection<CodeData> = db.collection(CODE_DATA_COLLECTION);
    if !read && !write {
        // delete
    }
    // update
    // find the code_data document in order to read the current memory breakpoints map
    let code_data: CodeData;
    match collection.find_one(doc! { "game": game_name }, None).await {
        Ok(result) => match result {
            Some(document) => {
                code_data = document;
            }
            None => {
                return ....;
            }
        },
        Err(_error) => {
            return ...;
        }
    }
    // create a sequence of breakpoints from start_address to end_address
    let mut memory_breakpoints_update = HashMap::new();
    for address in start_address..=end_address {
        memory_breakpoints_update.insert(address.to_string(), MemoryBreakpoint { read, write });
    }
    println!("memory_breakpoints_update {:?}", &memory_breakpoints_update);

    // current breakpoints overwritten by the new sequence
    let memory_breakpoints: HashMap<String, MemoryBreakpoint> = code_data
        .memory_breakpoints
        .into_iter()
        .chain(memory_breakpoints_update)
        .collect();
    println!("memory_breakpoints {:?}", &memory_breakpoints);

    let mut memory_breakpoints_bson = Document::new();
    memory_breakpoints.iter().for_each(|(k, v)| {
        memory_breakpoints_bson.insert(k.to_string(), doc! { "read": v.read, "write": v.write });
    });
    println!("memory_breakpoints_bson {}", memory_breakpoints_bson);

    match collection
        .update_many(
            doc! { "game": game_name },
            doc! { "$set": {
               "memory_breakpoints": memory_breakpoints_bson
            }},
            None,
        )
        .await
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update**

The solution based on the aggregation pipeline

```
    let collection: Collection<CodeData> = db.collection(CODE_DATA_COLLECTION);

    // TODO: use fold
    let mut update_object = Document::new();
    for address in start_address..=end_address {
        update_object.insert(address.to_string(), doc! { "read": read, "write": write });
    }

    let append = vec![doc! { "$set": {
       "memory_breakpoints": {
           "$mergeObjects": [ update_object, "$memory_breakpoints" ]
       }
    }}];

    let delete_object: Vec<String> = (start_address..=end_address)
        .map(|address| format!("memory_breakpoints.{}", address))
        .collect();
    println!("delete_object {:?}", delete_object);

    let delete = vec![doc! { "$unset":
         (delete_object)
    }];
    println!("delete {:?}", delete);

    let update_op = match read || write {
        true => append,
        false => delete,
    };

    match collection
        .update_many(doc! { "game": game_name }, update_op, None)
        .await
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between your shell example and the Rust code that is leading to the different outcomes.

If I take [your playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4ugz3ayBdhb) and [modify it just slightly](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DygrOvSTBCG) we effectively see the same output that you are getting with the Rust code:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "memory_breakpoints": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        {
          "10": {
            "read": false,
            "write": true
          },
          "11": {
            "read": false,
            "write": true
          }
        },
        "$memory_breakpoints"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

What did I change? I removed the `[` and `]` wrapping the second argument to the `update` which describes the modification that should happen. This matches the syntax that you currently have with the Rust code hence the similar results.

So what is going on? The second argument takes *either* a document or a pipeline. This makes a big difference as [`$mergeObjects` is an aggregation operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/). So when you use the *document* syntax of the `update` the database doesn't know that you are trying to instruct it to do something with `$mergeObjects` and instead just interprets it as a field name directly.

Also confusing, `$set` (along with other operators) mean different things in different contexts. It is both an [update operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) as well as  [an alias to the `$addFields` aggregation stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set). So by changing from the (aggregation) pipeline syntax to the document syntax you are also changing which `$set` operator is running (also contributing to the change in interpretation mentioned above).

The solution here is to wrap the second argument to the `update_many` method in your original Rust code with square brackets to make it an array.

Comment: I've learnt a great lesson 0 - ty. Updated the answer in order to reflect your idea