# Scala mongodb calculated field

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have mongoDB 4.4.4 version and mongoDB driver 4.7.2. When i try to update documents with calculated filed my expression doesn`t work. Expression in scala :

```
val update = new Document(
    "$set",
    new Document(
      s"created_at",
      new Document(
        "$toLong",
        new Document(
          "$toDate",
          "$_id"
        )
      )
    )
  )
db
  .getCollection(CollectionName)    
  .updateMany(
        new Document(),
        update
  )
```

But it make

```
 created_at=Document{{$toLong=Document{{$toDate=$_id}}}}
```

In Idea mongo console when i made

```
db.collection.updateMany({},[
    { "$set": { "created_at": {"$toLong": {"$toDate": "$_id" }}}}
])
```

`created_at` calc correctly.
How i can do something like it in scala code?

Comment: The second argument in your code needs to be an array (as it is in your shell console example). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
val update = Updates.set(
    s"created_at",
    new BsonDocument(
      "$toLong",
      new BsonDocument(
        "$toDate",
        new BsonString("$_id")
      )
    )
  )
db
  .getCollection(CollectionName)    
  .updateMany(
        new Document(),
        List(update).asJava
  )
```