# Set and pop update in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have db sample as:

```
db={
  "sample": [
    {
      current_book: "Aurthor",
      upcoming_book: [
        "Sigma",
        "Rocky"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to set current_book value to first element of upcoming_book and pop the first element out of upcoming_book.

**Expected O/P:**

```
[
  {
    "current_book": "Sigma",
    "upcoming_book": [
      "Rocky"
    ]
  }
]
```

For this I tried as:

```
db.sample.update({
  "upcoming_book.0": {
    $exists: true
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    current_book: {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        "$upcoming_book",
        0
      ]
    }
  },
  "$pop": {
    "upcoming_book": -1
  }
})
```

But it sets the value of current_book to the query provided and pops the value out of upcoming_book.

O/P:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "current_book": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$upcoming_book",
        0
      ]
    },
    "upcoming_book": [
      "Rocky"
    ]
  }
]
```

Also I tried aggregation pipeline:

```
db.sample.update({
  "upcoming_book.0": {
    $exists: true
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      current_book: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$upcoming_book",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$pop": {
      "upcoming_book": -1
    }
  }
])
```

But this throws the error as:

> fail to run update: (Location40324) Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$pop'.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/1j8DTlOHDV3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
[
  {
    "$set": {
      current_book: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$upcoming_book",
          0
        ]
      },
      "upcoming_book": {
        $slice: [
          "$upcoming_book",
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rBRB2ne2gfD) yields:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "current_book": "Sigma",
    "upcoming_book": [
      "Rocky"
    ]
  }
]
```

A more complete (dynamic size) solution would be:

```
[
  {
    "$set": {
      current_book: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$upcoming_book",
          0
        ]
      },
      "upcoming_book": {
        $slice: [
          "$upcoming_book",
          {
            $subtract: [
              1,
              {
                $size: "$upcoming_book"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/45BuHK2GHpj).

Part of your problem (`Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$pop'`) I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218).

Comment: Thank you for your help for the solution and the error reference link.