# Update, aggregation pipeline in pymongo with using $merge operation to update the collection which is deleting all existing fields in the nested field

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have mongodb version 5+ and latest version of pymongo from pip

I have query which update the $configuration.sql field perfectly fine

Issue: While updating the below $configuration.sql all other fields are lost in the resultset due to $merge statement. can someone correct me if I am missing something I am probably new to mongo queries?

INPUT DOCUMENT STRUCTURE
`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "639a60"
  },
  "status": "inactive",
  "version": "0.1",
  "configuration": {
    "identifier": "backfill-test",
    "secondaryIdentifier": "platform_type",
    "sql": "select * from test where lastupd_ts >= '2021-09-10 18:00:00' and lastupd_ts <= '2021-09-10 19:00:00'",
    "steps": [
      {
        "service": "Publish",
        "order": 1,
        "configuration": {
          "topic": "platform-type",
          "type": "PlatformType",
          "action": "N",
          "keyDeserializer": "serializers.Kafka",
          "valueDeserializer": "serializers.Deserializer"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "data-exporter-svc"
}
```

`
QUERY USED:

`

```
database.collection_name.aggregate(
[
        {"$match": {"configuration.identifier": "backfill-test"}},
        {
            "$project":
            {
                "configuration.sql": {"$replaceAll": {"input": "$configuration.sql", "find": "lastupd_ts >= \'2021-09-10 18:00:00\' and lastupd_ts <= \'2021-09-10 19:00:00\'", "replacement": "lastupd_ts >= \'2024-00-10 18:00:00\' and lastupd_ts <= \'2024-00-10 19:00:00\'"}}
            }
        },
        {
            "$merge": "collection_name"
        },
    ])
```

`QUERY RESULT`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "639a60"
  },
  "status": "inactive",
  "version": "0.1",
  "configuration": {
    "sql": "select * from test where lastupd_ts >= '2024-00-10 18:00:00' and lastupd_ts <= '2024-00-10 19:00:00'"
  },
  "name": "data-exporter-svc"
}
```

`

EXPECTED RESULT
`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "639a60"
  },
  "status": "inactive",
  "version": "0.1",
  "configuration": {
    "identifier": "backfill-test",
    "secondaryIdentifier": "platform_type",
    "sql": "select * from test where lastupd_ts >= '2024-00-10 18:00:00' and lastupd_ts <= '2024-00-10 19:00:00'",
    "steps": [
      {
        "service": "Publish",
        "order": 1,
        "configuration": {
          "topic": "platform-type",
          "type": "PlatformType",
          "action": "N",
          "keyDeserializer": "serializers.Kafka",
          "valueDeserializer": "serializers.Deserializer"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "data-exporter-svc"
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we could modify this to get it to work with `$merge`, I think the more straightforward approach would be to adapt this as an `update` directly. Since the `update` operation can take an aggregation pipeline to define the modification, this task should be relatively straightforward.

The translation requires doing the following:

1. Take the `$match` and use its contents as the first parameter to the `update` (the query filter with which to apply the change to).
2. Use the contents of the `$project` as the value for `$addFields` (or its alias `$set`) as the transformation being applied.
3. The `$merge` component is replaced by the command being an `update` rather than an `aggregate`.

It would look something like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "configuration.identifier": "backfill-test"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "configuration.sql": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$configuration.sql",
          "find": "lastupd_ts >= '2021-09-10 18:00:00' and lastupd_ts <= '2021-09-10 19:00:00'",
          "replacement": "lastupd_ts >= '2024-00-10 18:00:00' and lastupd_ts <= '2024-00-10 19:00:00'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZrNu5BDlsuW).

Note that I've removed the escape (backslash) characters which you may need to re-introduce depending on the language/quoting that you are using.

Also don't forget that `[{$set:{...}}]` and `{$set:{...}}` are different in this context, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218)