# Parse string in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Parsing a string in mongodb into alpha and numeric components.
Goal is to set new fields for each document with components of the string.

Desired result:

```
{ code: "A1357" }
```

parse to:

```
{ 
    code: 'A1357',
    codeAlpha: 'A',
    codeNum: 1357
}
```

The following parses the code, but sets codeAlpha and codeNum to expressions:

```
db.coll.updateMany({},{$set:{"codeAlpha":{$substrCP: ["$code",0,1]},"codeNum":{$toInt:{$substrCP: ["$code",1,4]}}}})
```

result:

```
{ 
  code: 'A1357',
  codeAlpha: ['{$substrCP': ['$code',0,1]}],
  codeNum: [{'$toInt':{'$substrCP': ['$code',1,4]}}]
}
```

How do I $set the actual value?

```
{ 
    code: 'A1357',
    codeAlpha: 'A',
    codeNum: 1357
}
```

Comment: Will letter always be only the first character and numbers remaining ones?

Comment: If you want to execute your update, you could do it in a pipeline by adding some brackets `[...]`.  Something like, https://mongoplayground.net/p/vyy83ldpG3X

Comment: More details about what the square brackets are doing is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218)