# Updating an object within an array and then grabbing a sum using an Aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a document set up like this:

```
//Game
{
number: "001",
players: [
    { 
        _id: ObjectId("123"),
        lives: 0
    },
    { 
        _id: ObjectId("124"),
        lives: 2
    },
    { 
        _id: ObjectId("125"),
        lives: 3
    },
],
totalLives: 5,
}
```

and what I want to do is set up an aggregrate pipeline that

1. sets the lives for a specific player (using `_id`) within a specific game (using `number`) -- in this example update player `123`
2. updates the totalLives sum for the game

I tried something like this until I realized (or rather I believe that) you need to use `aggregate()` to use the `$sum` operator.

```
await Games.updateOne(
            {
              number: game.number,
              "player._id": new ObjectId(newPlayer._id),
            },
            {
              $set: {
                "players.$[player].lives": newPlayer.lives,
                totalLives: { $sum: "$players.lives" },
              },
            },
            {
              arrayFilters: [{ "player._id": new ObjectId(newPlayer._id) }],
            }
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are only able to achieve this with aggregation pipeline.

1. `$set` - Update the `players` array. With `$map` to iterate each element in the `players` array, `$mergeObjects` with the current iterated element with the document contains `lives` fiel and assign value by condition (use existing value if not matched).
2. `$set` - Another stage after stage 1 to sum all the `players.lives` into `totalLives` field.

```js
await Games.updateOne({
  number: game.number,
  "player._id": new ObjectId(newPlayer._id),  
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      players: {
        $map: {
          input: "$players",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                lives: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this._id",
                        new ObjectId(newPlayer._id)
                      ]
                    },
                    then: newPlayer.lives,
                    else: "$$this.lives"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    $set: {
      totalLives: {
        $sum: "$players.lives"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UImcaXjCBl2)

Comment: is that "$$this" native or is that supposed to represent something else? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `"$$this"` is part of the `$map` operator, specifically the default for the `as` parameter. Docs [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/). Note though that while this answer does use the `$sum` aggregation operator, it is doing so _in_ an `update()` operation rather than an `aggregate()` as noted in the question. This is because `update()` can take an agg pipeline as its second argument. A bit more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218).

Comment: Although, is there a way without having to map them? I feel like there ought to be a way since we are provided the player's id of whom we're changing.