# mongoose casting mongodb query to string in findOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm fairly new to mongodb and I've been messing around with this for some time and can't get it right. I need to use a $set with a condition to set a field only if it doesn't exist:

```
$set: {
    theField: { $ifNull: ['$theField', '1234'] },
  }
```

this is passed in as `update: UpdateQuery<T>`which gives the error `"CastError: Cast to string failed for value \"{ '$ifNull': [ '$source7ChargeCode', '1234' ] }\" (type Object) at path \"source7ChargeCode\"\n    at model.Query.exec`

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Wrap your `$set` with square (and curly) brackets to make that argument an array containing a single object. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218) for more info

Comment: @user20042973 that didn't seem to work but it's also important to know it's being sent into this (as "update" object):
        .findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            ...this.getDeletedFilter(),
            ...filter,
            ...this.getAuthFilters(),
          },
            {
              ...update,
              ...{
                $set: {
                  ...update.$set,
                  ...this.getUserMutationObject(),
                },
              },
            },
          ,
        )

Comment: can you show your schema as well

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ifNull` just in `aggregation` nor in `update` query.

refer to [ifNull (aggregation)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) link for more info.

Comment: it looks like it's possible using aggregation pipeline via:

mongoose.UpdateWithAggregationPipeline | mongoose.UpdateQuery<OrganizationDocument>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice guys! Based on the responses I was able to see that I was using aggregation and to add these type queries to mongoose update methods you need to use UpdateWithAggregationPipeline object and then wrap it in [] to make it an array.