# Using UpdateMany to Add a New Field With The Value of Another Field as a String

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm trying to add a new field to all of my documents that contains the value of a number field, but as a string instead (in an effort to do both a rename and a type change for that field).

I tried this:

```
db.person.updateMany({}, {$set: { userId: {$toString:"$snowflake"} }})
```

Which gave me this:

[image: the userId was instead added as an object]

I've also tried just doing this:

```
db.person.updateMany({}, {$set: { userId:"$snowflake" }})
```

Which just inserted the value as "$snowflake". Everything I've seen suggests using existing fields this way, is there something I'm doing wrong?

MongoDB 6.0.6 Enterprise

Comment: The first attempt is so close. Wrap the second argument in square brackets. This makes it an array indicating that you are using aggregation pipeline syntax for the update. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218) for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$toString` in your query as a field because it is not used within an aggregation pipeline `[]`, hence creating an `userId` as an object with `$toString` as a field in it.

### Solution

Update your query as:

```
db.person.updateMany(
  {},
  [
    {
      $set: {
        userId: { $toString: "$snowflake" }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```