# Using $cond within update fail without errors, unable to toggle like/dislike on a model

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've tried to make a like/dislike operation but I want to make it in one query using the `$cond` operator.

It actually does not work and there is not any error so I can't really debug it.

Here's the model of the object I'm trying to update the liked/disliked properties:

```js
const articleSchema = new Schema({
    name : { type : String, unique: true, required : [true, 'Title is required']},
    description : { type : String, required : [true, 'Description is required']},
    price : { type : Number, required : [true, 'Price is required']}, 
    category : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'category', required : [true, 'Not a valid category']},
    images : [{type : String}],
    createdAt : {type: Date, default: () => Date.now()},
    creator : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users', required : [true, 'This is not a valid user']},
    liked : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'}],
    disliked : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'}],
  });
```

Note that my database has already a lot of existing `article` with `liked`/`disliked` properties already filled with some users, inserted using fixtures scripts.

Here's a representation of a `article` in my database for exemple

[image]

1. I've been trying with the following code but it does not produce any error so I can't debug it...

```js
const articleQ$ = articles.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: article }, 
    { $cond: [
        { liked: {$all: [user]} }, // If 'liked' array for this article contain this user
        { $pull: {liked: user} },  // If true ==> Remove the like
        { $push: {liked: user}, $pull: {disliked: user} } // If false, add the like and remove dislike in case there is a dislike on this one
      ]
    },
    {upsert: true}
  );

  return Promise.all([articleQ$]);
```

It seams like I'm using the [`$cond`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator correctly, so I don't really understand.

2. I've also tried using the [`$switch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/#mongodb-expression-exp.-switch) operator with no luck:

```js
const articleQ$ = articles.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: article }, 
    { $switch: {
      branches: [
          { case: {liked: {$all: [user]}}, then: {$pull: {liked: user}} }, 
        ],
        default: { $push: {liked: user}, $pull: {disliked: user} } 
      }
    },
    {upsert: true},
  );
```

3. I've been also trying to do it like the following. It work but this is not what I want to achieve:

```
const articleQ$ = articles.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: article }, 
    {$pull: {liked: user}}, // Remove user from liked array of this article
    {upsert: true},
  );
```

4. I've been trying yo wrap the second argument in a $set, but there is now an error:

> MongoError: Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.

```
const articleQ$ = articles.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: article }, 
    [
      { $set: {
          $cond: [
            { liked: {$all: [user]} }, 
            { $pull: {liked: user} }, 
            { $push: {liked: user}, $pull: {disliked: user} } 
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    {upsert: true},
  );
```

5. I've been trying a different approach, but I was maybe too ambitious on this one, and it does not work as I expected for some reason... Again, there is no errors, so I think something just does not match.

```
const articleQ$ = articles.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: article }, 
    [
      { $set: {
          liked: { 
            $cond: [
              { $in: [ user, "$liked" ] }, 
              { $setDifference: [ "$liked", [ user ] ] }, 
              { $concatArrays: [ "$liked", [ user ] ] } 
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    {upsert: true}
  );
```

Comment: `$switch` and `$cond` are both expressions that are available for use within the aggregation framework. But aggregations are _not_ the 'default' mode used for updates. Wrap your second argument in `[ { $set: ... } ]` and you'll get closer to what you want. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218) for a bit more context on the subtle differences between the modes

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've been trying your solution, and updated my question with the trial. It does not work the way I did. I probably made an other mistake

Comment: why not set the dislike field as well https://mongoplayground.net/p/DjwVQ8mkFd_

Comment: Thank you for your answer @cmgchess. I can't see any difference between your code and mine except that you added the dislike field. unfortunately it doesn't work.

It look like it should work, I can see it from your link  mongoplayground.net/p/DjwVQ8mkFd_

Comment: make sure the `user` is type ObjectID not string

Comment: Indeed, this is not an ObjectID, but just a user object, but I think this is resolved into an ObjectID since the following code work `{$pull: {liked: user}}`. Again, thank you very much for trying to help me