# updateMany while doing type change in mongoDB using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, updates

I have a use case to update data in a collection of mongoDB having avg size of 250kb.
Use case: convert datatype from String to Long for a field version.

I would like to do it in efficient way . Looking for options from Java and also through direct mongo queries.

MongoQuery found:

```
db.collection.updateMany({version : {$type: "string"}}, {$set: {version: {$toLong: "$version"}}})
```

Trying something like this below in java and not finding the version.

```
Bson filter = new Document("version", new Document("$type", "string"));
Bson newValue = new Document("version", *****);
Bson updateOperationDocument = new Document("$set", newValue);
collection.updateMany(filter, updateOperationDocument);
```

How to achieve this, not finding the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell the extent of your question. But you do mention that you are looking for the direct MongoDB query to achieve and there is an error in the one that you have shared so that's what this answer will focus on.

As we can see in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6lT1xm0so24), the update doesn't actually do what is intended. It shows us that documents such as the following:

```
  {
    _id: 2,
    version: "123"
  },
```

Get modified as follows:

```
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "version": {
      "$toLong": "$version"
    }
  },
```

The literal translation of `version` to `{ "$toLong": "$version" }` has to do with the semantics of the command as currently written. As outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218) there are actually two different `$set` operators in MongoDB. You're currently using the update modifier, but since you're referencing another field you are going to need to use the aggregation stage instead.

The good news is that the conversion is quite simple, just wrap the second argument to the command in square brackets. In this case we want to change it from:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {version : {$type: "string"}}, 
  {$set: {version: {$toLong: "$version"}}}
)
```

To:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {version : {$type: "string"}}, 
  [ {$set: {version: {$toLong: "$version"}}} ]
)
```

This alternative syntax yields results in the following change to the sample document that we looked at earlier:

```
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "version": NumberLong(123)
  },
```

See how it works in [this other playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2U0GJCWBxyY)