Why is it saving the whole mongodb clause not the timestamp?
When I am running it it's saving this whole clause
“$cond”: bson.M{
        “if”:   bson.M{“$eq”: bson.A{“$date”, nil}},
        “then”: time.Now(),
        “else”: “$date”,
    },

in the document. What did I do wrong here can anyone please explain? (I am using findOneAndupdate())
update[“$set”].(bson.M)[“date”] = bson.M{
            “$cond”: bson.M{
                “if”:   bson.M{“$eq”: bson.A{“$date”, nil}},
                “then”: time.Now(),
                “else”: “$date”,
            },
        }


If you are referencing fields in the documents in the update clause, then you need to use an update-aggregation. So the update should be an array of what you currently have after $set: [{ $set: { date: {$cond: {if: ...} }}]

It's giving me an error says indentifier or map expeced, got '['

bson.A to make it an array. See docs here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/reference/command/update/#update

Already tried that but it's not working :-(

How about using $ifNull like this?

In that case it's saving the whole $isNull clause

Are you using a really old version of MongoDB?

"Already tried that but it's not working" - what, specifically did you try? In what way is it not working? Edit your question to show us the details. The problem you're facing is either what aneroid or joe mentioned. Assuming it's not an ancient version that you're using, more info about the semantic differences between what you're doing and what you're trying to do (basically why the array is needed) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078046/subdocument-merge-issue-when-mongodb-rust-driver-is-used/74080218#74080218

Here is the doc I found helpful to understand what aneroid said and now it's working for me thanks!
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-go-driver-update-with-set-cond-aggregation-operator-works-only-when-wrapped-as-array/198416

@Napster Once you've updated your code to work, you should edit your community wiki answer below and add it there. (Otherwise, it's a "Link only answer" which may not be helpful to future readers.)

That community forum answer describes the same thing the SO answer I referenced above does, just with less detail.

Here is the updated code that worked for me -
update := bson.A{
            bson.M{
                "$set": bson.M{
                    "field1": field1_Value,
                    "field2": field2_Value,
                },
            },
        }
       
    
update = append(update, bson.M{
                "$set": bson.M{
                    "field3": field3_value,
                    "field4":  bson.M{"$ifNull": []interface{}{"$field4", field4_value}},
                },
            })

I found this doc helpful thank you aneroid for commenting-
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-go-driver-update-with-set-cond-aggregation-operator-works-only-when-wrapped-as-array/198416
